# Laravel JOIN query with 2 conditions out of which one is NULL

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, null, where-clause

I need a query where I want to join tables, on 2 conditions in OR. Out of these 2 condition is to check whether the column `IS NULL`.

```
$query->select('users.*', 'o.name', 'r.name')
                     ->join('owners as o', 'users.owner_id', '=', 'o.id')
                     ->join('residents as r', 'users.resident_id', '=', 'r.id');
```

In the above query I also want to check if the `users.resident_id IS NULL` i.e., `users.resident_id = r.id OR users.resident_id IS NULL`.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i haven't try this..

how about use "right join" sql..

from w3school..
SQL RIGHT JOIN Keyword. The RIGHT JOIN keyword returns all records from the right table (table2), and the matched records from the left table (table1). The result is NULL from the left side, when there is no match.

if this not working then use "whereIn"..
select all id with null data first, then select all id from join.. then you can use whereIn to select all data with id from data1 and data2..

Comment: Thanks @Hidayat Riva, your answer gave me the clue to use left join. Right join didn't work, however, left join worked like a charm !